# ./ looks full but its actually space used in ./ZFS/

Tags: mount, zfs

foo has failed me and I'm sure this is a simple thing but...

Short version. 
I want to be able to configure the application KVM/QEMU/Virtual Machine Manager so it does not monitor my / mount point in such a way that it sees the drive full when the data is on another mount point
How do I exclude a File System mounted in / from the calculation of what is in the actual boot disk, in my case md1. Thanks

long version

So I noticed my lab VMs stop responding and it turned out they had paused. 
Usual thing would be disk space so I did a

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            65919500         0  65919500   0% /dev
tmpfs           13197136     10848  13186288   1% /run
/dev/md1       394860308 363170492  11562328  97% /
tmpfs           65985672         0  65985672   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           65985672         0  65985672   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           13197132        16  13197116   1% /run/user/124
tmpfs           13197132        12  13197120   1% /run/user/1000
```

Followed by a

```
du -hx | sort -h
*SNIP*
2.9G    ./ZFS/BIG/BSD
2.9G    ./ZFS/BIG/Linux
3.5G    ./usr
4.1G    ./ZFS/Enduro
4.1G    ./ZFS/Enduro/WINDOWS
4.1G    ./ZFS/Enduro/WINDOWS/SQL_DATA
9.4G    ./ZFS/BIG/windows/Desktop
27G     ./ZFS/BIG/windows/WIN_SQL
29G     ./ZFS/BIG/windows/DC01
268G    ./ZFS/BIG/windows/WIN_FS_1
332G    ./ZFS/BIG/windows
337G    ./ZFS/BIG
341G    ./ZFS
347G    .
```

to see where the space was taken.

I freed some space and resumed the VM's before shutting them down.

I want to be able to configure the application KVM/QEMU/Virtual Machine Manager so it does not monitor my / mount point in such a way that it sees the drive full when the data is on another mount point
How do I exclude a File System mounted in / from the calculation of what is in the actual boot disk, in my case md1.

Many Thanks

Whilst I'm still interested in a way to avoid the issue if using flat files here is my work around. The BigPool will also store files.

I've created new pools:

```
zfs create -V 44G -s BigPool/BSD_FW_Router
```

Made a partition table:

```
parted /dev/BigPool/BSD_FW_Router mklabel gpt
```

Copied the image to the new volume:

```
dd if=/ZFS/BIG/BSD/FW/Router-FW.qcow2 | pv -s 44 | dd of=/dev/BigPool/BSD_FW_Router bs=16M
```

and reconfigured the VM to start from the device /dev/BigPool/BSD_FW_Router for this example.